# "t" key always pressed on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, bug

For some reason, my Mac keyboard always thinks that the "t" key is always being pressed. However as you can see I can still type in the letter t, but it comes out delayed compared to the other keys. I think it is a software bug as the key still works fine, but on some pages the t key just gets spammed. Oddly enough, shift+t won't give me an uppercase t, but all the other letters work fine (and my caps lock has been converted to a backspace, so I can't test that (by choice)). this has happened before, but typically goes away after a restart, but this one time a restart didn't help.

Edit: Currently on Macbook Air (1 generation ago)

Comment: Try an external keyboard.  If it does not show the same problem, that's a good indication the internal one is damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, it was actually a software bug. To fix this one must reset the SMC, more information can be found at this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). To reset, one must turn off the computer then hold the shift + control + option key and the power button (all together for 10 seconds). Then turn on the computer as you normally would.

Update: While this mostly worked. I have found that it was still giving me the same problem. Upon further investigation I needed to update ‘Karabiner-Keys’ which is an application that allows you to change the mapping of your keys. A bug in the software was the reason for the spamming of the key at random. Keep your software updated :)

Comment: Edited! Nice catch

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but most likely your "T" key has a crumb of food or some dust stuck underneath it.

Canned air sometimes works, but sometimes will jam it in there for good.

If it's still under AppleCare, bring it in to an Apple store and look distressed...sometimes it helps to cry a little bit and/or beg. Personally, I just grab a Genius' pant leg and refuse to let go while sobbing loudly.

Generally they can replace the key and/or keyboard, but you may need to go without your laptop for a week.